# Push notification using Laravel , recieved messages are overlapping, How to recover it?

Tags: laravel, notifications, push

I have done my push notification using laravel. But notifications are overlapping on my mobile. How to show the count and logo.It should not overlap

Comment: android, ios, windows mobiles ?
can you post a screenshot of it

Comment: show some code?

Comment: Hi i got solution for this issue. i have added the 'notid' attribute in my message parameters. here is my code          $message = PushNotification::Message($msg,array(
        'message'=> $msg,
        'title'=>$title,
            'image'=>$image,
        'additionalData'=>$openUrl,
        'actionLocKey' => 'View',
       
            'notId' =>rand(10,100),
        'locKey' => 'localized key',
        'locArgs' => array(
          'localized args',
          'localized args',
          ),
      )

Answer (score 0):

Hi i got solution for this issue. i have added the 'notid' attribute in my message parameters. here is my code
       $message = PushNotification::Message($msg,array('message'=> $msg,
        'title'=>$title,'notId' =>rand(10,100),'locKey' => 'localized key','locArgs' => array('localized args','localized args'),
      )
);